# Fire Mongoose validation failure in model presave

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I would like to create a validator for Mongoose that causes `.save()` to fail if the row already exists. At the moment my validators look somewhat like this (coffee):

```
model.schema.path('email').validate (email) =>
  return email? and email.length > 0
, 'BLANK_EMAIL'
```

However, they are synchronous and therefore having a `@model.find` checking for length inside there would not work. I was considering using something like the pseudo-code below but I don't know if it's possible, or if there's a much easier method that will follow the same mongoose validation pattern I'm already using. Thanks!

```
model.schema.pre 'save', (next) ->
  self = @
  model.find {email: self.email}, (err, rows) ->
    if rows.length
      # This bit is the pseudo-code:
      model.schema.path('email').validate false
    next()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#schematype_SchemaType-validate

```
schema.path('email').validate(function (value, respond) {
  mongoose.model("user").count({email: this.email}, function(err, num) {
    respond(!(err || num)); // validation failed
  })
 }, '{PATH} failed validation.');
```

You might want to check for `email: this.email, _id: {$ne: this._id}`, depending on your needs. The above snippet is untested, but you get the general idea.

Validators with two arguments (value & a callback) run asynchronously, as opposed to validators with a single argument (value), which must return a boolean. The callback receives a boolean which indicates that the error should be thrown. AFAIK, you can't pass an `Error` instance to the callback.

Comment: Ah, a callback parameter! I hadn't seen that- I don't know if it's just me or the Mongoose docs aren't the easiest to traverse. Thanks, I'll give it a try.

Comment: Ps. I got the code in my question to work by actually just doing `next(new Error('Email failed validation'))`, but I'd imagine the Mongoose async validation method is cleaner and probably has added benefits.

Comment: Yeah, you can also pass an `Error` in your pre-save hook, but I prefer to do things in the validators; you'll be able to do `if(error instanceof MongooseValidationError)` and handle errors accordingly. But then again, there's nothing wrong with your alternative approach.

Comment: Okay, cheers. I've gone with your method as that is basically the type of thing that I was already looking for and it works a treat. Appreciate the help :)